# Azure Devops Parallel SQL Backups

Tags: sql, azure-devops

I am trying to set up a job as part of a software deployment that requires backups of two SQL Databases housed on separate servers, these backups needs to be initiated at the same time.  I am using deployment group jobs for all of the other steps in my release pipeline, these are agents running on servers in my organization (non-cloud).

I have a release pipeline where I am successfully backing up one database as part of a software deployment. I have a separate deployment requiring the backup of two separate databases simultaneously. I have not been able to find an option in devops to either run two tasks at the same time, or run two jobs at the same time. Every option that I have tried simply runs things in sequence. Does anyone know how to accomplish running two or more tasks / jobs in parallel in a release pipeline?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Your question seems to be lacking and actual question. What are you asking about? Are you having a problem with something? If so, tell us what the problem is, and what you've tried to solve that problem. Be specific and provide any error messages or codes you might be getting.

Comment: Hi, Sorry about that.  I have a release pipeline where I am successfully backing up one database as part of a software deployment.  I have a separate deployment requiring the backup of two separate databases simultaneously.  I have not been able to find an option in devops to either run two tasks at the same time, or run two jobs at the same time.  Every option that I have tried simply runs things in sequence.  Does anyone know how to accomplish running two or more tasks / jobs in parallel in a release pipeline?

Comment: Why do you need to run both backups at the same time? Why can't you do the operations sequentially?

Comment: This is a requirement for the application, if one database has data not existing in the other, it causes problems.  I tried to fight that battle in the past and lost.

Comment: That doesn't explain why you need to initiate two backups at the exact same time. I'm having a hard time just wrapping my head around the requirement to BACKUP a database as part of a software deployment. If you really, absolutely, MUST perform two backups are part of the deployment process, you should initiate each backup sequentially BEFORE the app code gets deployed. That would let you get around any weird data existence requirements by the app.

Comment: this backup occurs in one application, then is restored into another application.  If the backups aren't from the same time, when they are restored into the second application, then it causes problems and the process has to be repeated.  I personally dislike how the application is set up, but it's pretty set in stone.  I had suggested in the past to simply take both databases offline, then perform the backup sequentially, but the application can't be taken offline either.

Answer (score 1):

Tasks in an agent phase in a release pipeline does not currently support dependencies like build pipelines, so will not support parallel agent phase execution.  Tasks in a deployment group phase will execute in parallel on every server in the chosen deployment group that matches the given tag if one is provided.  The tasks defined in a deployment group phase will execute the same on all machines, so it is not possible from the pipeline to pass in unique parameter values (DB-name/Credentials) specific to server for deployment groups.  You'll have to manage those unique parameters a different way, possibly as environment variables on the server that can be referenced by the release task.

So, if you have two DB server configured with the deployment group agent with the tag "DB" and create a deployment group phase with your backup task that targets that deployment group for servers with the DB tag ... those tasks will run in parallel on the two servers.

Comment: Parallel agent phases in release pipelines is a planned feature that should be in development, so this info will become stale at some point.

Comment: I read that it was not currently supported as well, however I got this today from the MS website:  "If you want Azure Pipelines to orchestrate your builds and releases, but use your own machines to run them, use self-hosted parallel jobs."  This looks like it is possible.

Comment: I don't think that the parallel part was the intention.  Executing the pipeline tasks you can either use a Microsoft-hosted agent or you can host the agents on your own servers (Self-hosted).  Can see if anyone else has thoughts, but I've spent quite a bit of time trying to get parallel operation on release pipelines and I just don't believe it exists outside of the duplicate task execution during deployment group phases until they release the phase dependency feature to release pipelines.

Comment: Is there public information regarding what you are referring to about upcoming support?

Comment: You can upvote my [feature request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/360521/pipelines-allow-deployment-group-phases-to-run-in.html).  The discussion about it in the backlog from this [similar issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/2032#issuecomment-451905376) on github.